# Missing header in the UI - Vue.js

Tags: vue.js

[image]

I need my h1 to show below my  for my checkbox. It is inside of the div. Should I maybe put it outside of the .

The missing  is below the Organization Fields header. It is suppose to display below the checkbox input but it is not showing at all. What may cause it to disappear

**HTML**

```
<label name="Organization">Show Organization Data</label>
 <input type="checkbox" :v-model="showOrganizationFields" :true-value="true" :false-value="false">
 <div v-if="showOrganizationFields">
  <h1 class="mb-7 mt-5 ml-6 font-bold text-2xl"> Organization Fields</h1>
  <div v-for="field in requiredOrganizationFields" class="p-8 -mr-6 -mb-6 flex flex-wrap" style="width:150px">
    <label :for="field" type="select" name="field">{{field}}</label>
    <select :id="field" :name="field" v-model="mapping[field]" required>
      <option value="">Please Select</option>
      <option v-for="columnName in columnNames" :name="columnName" :value="columnName"  value="">{{columnName}}</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review. Asking for advice on code yet to be written or implemented is off-topic for this site. See [What topics can I ask about?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for reference. Once you have written working code, you're welcome to ask a new question here and we can then help you improve it!

Comment: It works if I remove the label. Doesn't work If I add a label for the checkbox. I need the label for the input. Can't have an opening and closing input tag

Comment: Well, regardless, this is not the right place to ask about fixing code. You might check Stack Overflow instead, they specialize in that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add the  tag above the  &  tags

```
<h1 class="mb-7 mt-5 ml-6 font-bold text-2xl">Organization Fields</h1>
 <label class="ml-6 mt-6 mb-6 text-medium" name="Organization">Show Organization Data</label>
 <input type="checkbox" :v-model="showOrganizationFields" :true-value="true" :false-value="false">
 <div v-if="showOrganizationFields">
  <div v-for="field in requiredOrganizationFields" class="p-8 -mr-6 -mb-6 flex flex-wrap" style="width:150px">
    <label :for="field" type="select" name="field">{{field}}</label>
    <select :id="field" :name="field" v-model="mapping[field]" required>
      <option value="">Please Select</option>
      <option v-for="columnName in columnNames" :name="columnName" :value="columnName"  value="">{{columnName}}</option>
    </select>
```

Comment: Please do not answer off-topic questions.